# How to get enter events on widgets in GTK (Rust)

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk4

In a Rust GTK application I'm trying to get an enter event on a custom Grid widget and it isn't registering. Using the same handler definition on a Button does get the enter events so I know the setup is basically right.

I've looked online. Old StackOverflow questions talk about a wrapping it in a BoxEvent, but I believe that advice is out of date in GTK4. In GTK docs I've seen something about needing to activate the widget, and GTK3 has EventMask, but it is not in GTK4 and I can't find anything with similar functionality. I have set the widgets focusable, but that does not make a difference. The sample code does not have anything with enter or motion events. Does anyone see what I am missing?

```
    let enter_handler = EventControllerMotion::new();
    enter_handler.connect_motion(|z, x, y| {println!("entered Grid{:#?} ({}, {})", z, x, y);});
    self.obj().add_controller(&enter_handler);
```

Comment: For `enter` events shouldn't you use `connect_enter()` instead of `connect_motion()`?

Comment: @rodrigo   Oops, yes, you're right, I cut this example from when I tried getting motion events to see if I could get them, and it had the same problem. Motion events and enter events both behave the same, the Button gets them but the Grid doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I found it - for anyone else looking, the property is "can-target"

Comment: I know that naming things is hard... but this is silly.